# Calling children inside getChildByName / getChild At?

Tags: actionscript-3

I found out that I can't target a object inside the main MC if I use getChildAt / getChildByName. It will return me

```
Error #1119: Access of possibly undefined property someProperty through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.
```

I was trying to use something like

```
this.getChildAt(0).getChildByName("objectName")....
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getChildByName` and other get child methods return an object of type `DisplayObject`. You must cast it appropriately before properties or methods not belonging to display objects. Also bear in mind that these get child methods belong to `DisplayObjectContainer` class - so you cannot chain like the way you're trying to do.

```
var container:DisplayObjectContainer = DisplayObjectContainer(getChildAt(3));
var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(container.getChildByName("intro_movie"));
mc.gotoAndStop(4);

//or

var container:DisplayObjectContainer = getChildAt(3) as DisplayObjectContainer;
var mc:MovieClip = container.getChildByName("intro_movie") as MovieClip;
mc.gotoAndStop(4);

//or
MovieClip(DisplayObjectContainer(getChildAt(3)).getChildByName("intro_movie")).gotoAndStop(4);
```

Casting with `ClassName(obj)` syntax will throw an error if cast fails; casting with `obj as ClassName` returns null without any errors - this might lead to confusions later as it can lead to error 1009 (null reference) at unexpected locations.